# View comma separated values of one column in multiple rows or in multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a shopping website in which I have saved multiple values in one column in my database.

The column name is "availablesize" and the stored values are "S,M,L,XL".
Now I want to view these three values in separate rows.

Here's my code:

```html
<div>      <!-- Added by edit -->
  <div>    <!-- Added by edit -->

<?php


require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT productid,productname,availablesize FROM products WHERE productid=:uid');
 
 $stmt->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 extract($row);
 
}
else
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
 

?>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="requiresize" value="<?php echo $availablesize;?>" checked>
    <label for="red"><span class="sizespan"><?php echo $availablesize;?></span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  type="radio" id="blue" name="requiresize"  value="<?php echo $availablesize;?>">
    <label for="blue"><span class="sizespan"><?php echo $availablesize;?></span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  type="radio" id="black" name="requiresize" value="<?php echo $availablesize;?>">
    <label for="black"><span class="sizespan"><?php echo $availablesize;?></span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  type="radio" id="black" name="requiresize" value="<?php echo $availablesize;?>">
    <label for="black"><span class="sizespan"><?php echo $availablesize;?></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added two `<div>`s to make your HTML _well-formed_ and _valid_
.

Comment: Consider normalising your schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why multiple explodes were listed in previous answer/comment. Seems like unnecessary redundant use of a function call.

```
<?php
  $sizes = explode("," , $availablesize);
  $small = $sizes[0];
  $med = $sizes[1];
  $large= $sizes[2];
  $xlarge = $sizes[3];
```

Now, the variables listed above will contain "S", "M", "L", and "XL". 
OR, you could simply display:

```
    <?php echo $sizes[0];  ?>
    <?php echo $sizes[1];  ?>
    <?php echo $sizes[2];  ?>
    <?php echo $sizes[3];  ?>
```

Just a matter of preference in how you want to display them. By creating specific variables, you'd be able to use them elsewhere if you want.

Comment: @muAuley thanks , but i have problem in this code now as i am fetching data from database so some time there will be all values like "S,M,L,XL,XXL" BUT some time there are only 2 values like "S,M" so that time it shows error, how to fetch automatically length that of avalaiblesize and show automatically without using like 0,1 2,3 automatically.

Comment: Just use the "count" function. Like this:   $cnt = count( $sizes);  That will tell you how many items you have. To get the index of the last one, it would simply be  $cnt = count( $sizes) - 1;   Since you don't know what size is going to be in which index, then you'd have to get a bit more complicated if you want to use those variable names I mentioned -- maybe by using DEFINE constants. Otherwise, just use the $sizes[n] paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo explode(',', $availablesize)[0];?> = S
<?php echo explode(',', $availablesize)[1];?> = M
<?php echo explode(',', $availablesize)[2];?> = S
<?php echo explode(',', $availablesize)[3];?> = XL
```

Comment: The qualify of this answer we be greatly improved if you explained your code.

Comment: @burhan thanks , i have problem in this code now as i am fetching data from database so some time there will be all values like "S,M,L,XL,XXL" BUT some time there are only 2 values like "S,M" so that time it shows error, how to fetch automatically length that of avalaiblesize and show automatically without using like 0,1 2,3 automatically.

Comment: $availablesize = explode(',', $availablesize);

foreach($availablesize as $size):
?>
<div>
 <input type="radio" id="red" name="requiresize" value="<?php echo $size;?>" checked>
 <label for="red"><span class="sizespan"><?php echo $size;?></span></label>
</div>
<?php
endforeach;